# how to replace all occurrences of html elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a javascript module to replace all occurrences of html elements that has the class `.item2`. but my code below only replaces the last occurrence and erases the other occurrences. what am I doing wrong?

```
// before replacement
/* 
first one;first two;first three;
second one;second two;second three;
another one;another two;another three; 
*/

// expected result
/* 
first one;Hellofirst three;
second one;Hellosecond three;
another one;Helloanother three; 
*/

// what I currently get
/* 
first one;first three;
second one;second three;
another one;Helloanother three; 
*/
```

```js
const c1 = document.querySelector('#container1');
const c2 = document.querySelector('#container2');
const c3 = document.querySelector('#container3');

let str = '<span class="item1">first one;</span>';
c1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
str = '<span class="item2">first two;</span>';
c1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
str = '<span class="item3">first three;</span>';
c1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);

str = '<span class="item1">second one;</span>';
c2.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
str = '<span class="item2">second two;</span>';
c2.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
str = '<span class="item3">second three;</span>';
c2.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);

str = '<span class="item1">another one;</span>';
c3.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
str = '<span class="item2">another two;</span>';
c3.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
str = '<span class="item3">another three;</span>';
c3.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);

let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.item2');
console.log('all children', elems);
str = '<span data-rpl="item2" class="new">Hello</span>';
let newElem = makeElem(str);

elems.forEach((item, key) => {
  console.log('each', key, item);
  item.replaceWith(newElem);
});

function makeElem(str) {
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  template.innerHTML = str;
  return template.content.firstChild;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1"></div>

<div id="container2"></div>

<div id="container3"></div>
```

Comment: You are inserting the same new element (`newElem`) multiple times, and since a single element can only exist in one place in the DOM, it is being left at the last place it was inserted. You should be able to move the `let newElem = ...` inside the loop to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like you have a loop on .items2 you have to insert another tag in DOM for each element of the loop

an idea can be to clone the newElem with

```
 item.replaceWith(newElem.cloneNode(true));
```

```js
const c1 = document.querySelector('#container1');
const c2 = document.querySelector('#container2');
const c3 = document.querySelector('#container3');

let str = '<span class="item1">first one;</span>';
c1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
str = '<span class="item2">first two;</span>';
c1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
str = '<span class="item3">first three;</span>';
c1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);

str = '<span class="item1">second one;</span>';
c2.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
str = '<span class="item2">second two;</span>';
c2.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
str = '<span class="item3">second three;</span>';
c2.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);

str = '<span class="item1">another one;</span>';
c3.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
str = '<span class="item2">another two;</span>';
c3.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
str = '<span class="item3">another three;</span>';
c3.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);

let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.item2');
//console.log('all children', elems);
str = '<span data-rpl="item2" class="new">Hello</span>';
let newElem = makeElem(str);

elems.forEach((item, key) => {
  console.log('each', key, item);
  item.replaceWith(newElem.cloneNode(true));
});

function makeElem(str) {
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  template.innerHTML = str;
  return template.content.firstChild;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1"></div>

<div id="container2"></div>

<div id="container3"></div>
```